# Powershell Host that supports breakpoints/debugging

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell

How can I create a PSHost that supports breakpoints/debugging in Powershell?
Are there special functions I need to implement for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace` contains the property [Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.debugger%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Add a handler to its event `DebuggerStop` and process these events in your host.

Comment: Can you please help answering this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221641/debug-job-the-job-cannot-be-debugged-because-the-host-debugger-mode-is-set-to-n